# SyntaxError for "from neuralintents import GenericAssistant"

Tags: discord, discord.py

(this is my first post here sorry if I do things wrong)

I'm making a discord bot and I wanted to experiment with intents but when I try to run my code it says there's a syntax error, I've installed everything in the right place and there's no errors in the code itself only when I run it. Help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

error text:

```
    Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
invalid syntax (pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py, line 114)
  File "E:\Bot thing\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from neuralintents import GenericAssistant
```

All the code relevant to neuralintents is:

```
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant

chatbot = GenericAssistant("intents.json")
chatbot.train_model()
chatbot.save_model()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. All code here seems to have valid syntax

Comment: yeah... all code seems to have valid syntax but the error wont stop, thats why im asking this question. Has this happened to anyone else maybe? I have no idea whats causing the issue.

Comment: So running *exactly* and *only* this code produces the error? An [online check](https://extendsclass.com/python-tester.html) shows that this is valid syntax. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: yes, running exactly this and only this code shows the error - I've tried re-installing everything and even recreating the code in another file from scratch and nothing is working. It seems ridiculous but it just wont work..

Comment: The error makes me think that it looks like a problem with the *library*, not your problem. What's the text at and around line 114 of `pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py`?

Comment: "def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
    return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async)
TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync = _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync"

Comment: errors - "(" was not closed
and "async" expected perameter name and expected expression